# Downloading images from an URL - doesn't seem to work

Tags: r

I have this R code, that should download an image, from an URL, to disk.

The code below runs and produces a session output as shown below and yet when I try to open the JPEG file - the actual image is always missing. The file seems "empty" -  though the size of the file actually matches the URL size.

Code:

```
setInternet2(use = TRUE)
url <- "http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/7ia/Kxq/7iaKxqrKT.jpeg"
destination="shuttle.jpg"
download.file(url,destination)
```

R Session output:

```
trying URL 'http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/7ia/Kxq/7iaKxqrKT.jpeg'
Content type 'image/jpeg' length 14550 bytes (14 KB)
downloaded 14 KB
```

And - I read some replies indicating that the code works fine with some without the first line (setInternet2). I tried with and without that line - but it still does not work.

I have tried with with https:// urls and it had not worked - so tried with this http://, but it just doesn't work

Here's the error message I get - when I double click and try to view the jpg file in picture-viewer:

```
"Windows PhotoViewer can't open this picture because either PhotoViewer doesn't support this file format or you don't have the latest updates to PhotoViewer"
```

thanks a lot for your help
rajesh

Comment: which package `setInternet2` belongs to? without the first line of code, your code works well for me.

Comment: `setInternet2()` is part of R when running on Windows.

Comment: Thank you @DirkEddelbuettel for this information. I am on Mac I did not know about that function.

Comment: And only when running *natively* on Windows; Cygwin R does not have `setInternet2()` either. (Although I've read that Cygwin is not officially supported by the R folks, so I suppose my R session might blow up at any moment...)

Comment: @RajeshS, what do you mean by "it doesn't hold the image"? You should have a file called shuttle.jpg on your disk. Your code downloads and stores in the destination the jpeg found at url just fine. Works for all of us.

Comment: @Sparky - I modified my original post - hope it is clearer now. The file is "empty"  - it has the same size as the source URL - but when i try to open it -  there is no picture content

Answer (score 1):

It worked :) I figured out a way :)

I added `mode = "wb"` - to the `download` command - this downloads in "binary" format - and it worked.

rajesh